# ARI - wscat getting error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: asterisk

my server bind to 0.0.0.0 but while running the below command getting the error

[root@asterisk]# wscat -c "ws://localhost:8088/ari/events?api_key=asterisk:asterisk&app=hello-world" error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Please suggest.

Using Asterisk 13.12.2

Answer (score 0):

Check `http.conf` and in `[general]` section and make sure that `enabled = yes`.

Comment: Can you share ari.conf, http.conf. Stasis client and asterisk server are running in same machine right?

Comment: ari.conf
[general]
enabled = yes       ; When set to no, ARI support is disabled.
pretty = no        ; When set to yes, responses from ARI are

[asterisk]
type = user
read_only = no
password = test8123

Comment: http.conf
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr=127.0.0.1

Yes on the same machine